# Making part of lines layer transparent based on circle

Tags: qgis, symbology

I have lines from a centerpoint going outwards at 10 degree intervals. I want to make the inner portion within the black circle of those lines transparent (25%). How can I do this?

[image]

Comment: How are your data structured ? Do u have an ID for each line ?

Comment: hello, each line was on a different layer, i combined them all in 1 layer. can i add an ID using the attribute Table?

Comment: Could inner segments be detached from the outer ones?

Comment: no they are lines from the center point outwards for a fixed distance, all of them.

Answer (score 5):

I would try layered **Geometry generator** lines for this.

Open the layer properties of your line layer (`radial_spokes` in this example) and create two stacked Geometry generators (by hitting green 'plus' button at the upper right corner).

[image]

(1) Make the first geometry generator layer for lines Within the circle by:

```
intersection($geometry, geometry(get_feature_by_id('circle', 1)))
```

(
if the layername of your circle is `'circle'` and your circle has an id = 1).

(2) Then set opacity (transparency) to 25% (or 75%?) for this part.

[image]

(3) Next, make the second geometry generator for lines outside of the circle by:

```
difference($geometry, geometry(get_feature_by_id('circle', 1)))
```

(The color for the lines outside of the circle is kept unchanged).

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer, this created a new black colored layer on top of it. i must add the circle is a polygon with fill set to full transparent and the border is visible, that is what is creating the circle. the spokes were each on 1 different line layer, i managed to merge the spoke lines into 1 layer. but i cannot merge the circle and the lines layers.

Comment: @SSR2000 Can you add an image to explain what is happening? As you see it on my example, the lines and circle layers are separated. You do not have to merge them.

Comment: @SSR2000 Have you changed the syntax to fit your data? For instance `'circle'` should be the layername of your circle.

Comment: Yes i put the actual name of the layer that contains that circle

Comment: @SSR2000 ... and you are still getting the black layer? Is is possible for you to post how it looks on your `layer properties` setting?

Comment: hi, i tried doing this again, step by step, but i end up with the same results as before. i have set the code for the first part and the code for the second part, when i hit apply, i get the same results now as what i had. even if i set the transparency to 1% for the part inside the circle it doesn't appear to work. here is an image for the settings: 
1) https://ibb.co/6v4RZw1    
2) https://ibb.co/mq7zfx1

Comment: @SSR2000 Your setting looks fine to me. Just one question: Did you apply the setting to the line layer which going outward from the centerpoint? Not the circle layer?

Comment: i applied the geometry generator to the Lines layer, a Duplicate of that layer to be exact, to be sure that i don't mess it up. i really appreciate it that you take the time to try to help me out with this quest but i don't know why it isn't working. is it a python script? do i need to download and install python separately?

Comment: @SSR2000 Only thing I can think of...... your Lines layer might be a multipart object. (If it is the case, the attribute table will show only one row). Could you try **Multipart to Singleparts** tool? It is under the menu `Vector > Geometry tools`.

Comment: Yes, indeed, they were drawn with a plugin tool at specific intervals. so each line was on a New temporary layer. i managed to merge them all into 1 layer. but in the attribute table there is a record for each of the lines individually.

Comment: @SSR2000 Umm, then al the settings are same as mine. This is my last question: is your `CIRCLE 5M'` layer Polygon or Line? (Because my answer is assuming your circle is closed polygon).

Comment: the circle was also generated with a plugin, i think it was saved as a line, i see a line symbol in my layer panel, it also says Simple Line. maybe that is the issue. should it be a polygon? what are my options? can we work with a circle line layer instead or do i need to convert it to polygon instead?

Comment: @SSR2000 Then, could you convert the Line (circle) into a polygon and use it as a new Circle layer? There is a tool **Lines to polygons** in the `Processing Tool > Vector geometry`.

Comment: i have converted the circle to polygon and still can't get it to work. i have redone everything from step 1 again but still no luck. i think i'll just leave it as is. thank you very much for your effort and time.